# Loop if issues with peripheral

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im working on Peripheral Scanner and i have problem with if loop.
I get errors: "Expected condition in for statement" and "Braced blocks of statement is an unused closure". This is this loop:

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverServices error: NSError!)
{
    if let servicePeripheral = peripheral.services as? [CBService]
    {
       for peripheral.services in CBService
        {
        println("\(servicePeripheral)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is badly formed.  You have:

```
for <some existing value> in <a data type> {
}
```

instead you want:

```
for <new variable> in <some collection> {
}
```

Perhaps you meant to loop over the `[CBService]` (array of `CBService`):

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverServices error: NSError!)
{
    if let servicePeripherals = peripheral.services as? [CBService]
    {
        for servicePeripheral in servicePeripherals
        {
            println("\(servicePeripheral)")
        }
    }
}
```